# Interrupting Ruby threads with Signal

Tags: ruby, multithreading, signals

I have split a program between main thread and a worker thread. I want to call a software interrupt that interrupts everything but it seems to only interrupt the main thread.

A simplified proof of concept is following. I define a trap and have another thread call a Process.kill to create the interrupt.

```
Signal.trap("INT") do 
  Thread.new {
    puts "int 1"
    sleep 5
    puts "int 2"
    sleep 5
  }.join
end

int_thread = Thread.new {
  Process.kill("INT", Process.pid)
}

work_thread = Thread.new {
  puts "work 1"
  sleep 5
  puts "work 2"
  sleep 5  
  puts "work 3"
  sleep 5
}

puts "main 1"
sleep 5
puts "main 2"
sleep 5
puts "main 3"
sleep 5
```

=>

```
main 1
work 1
int 1 # interrupt called here
work 2 # worker thread still running
int 2
work 3
main 2 # main thread continues after interrupt
main 3
```

Why is the worker thread not affected by the interrupt? Is there something i'm do wrong? Is there any way i could call an interrupt for the worker thread?

Comment: As you handle the signal in the main thread, the main thread has to process it and then continue business as normal. If you put the handling in the worker thread, it will be the one to process it. Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: I'm not sure, when i declare the trap and call Process.kill inside the worker thread it still only interrupts the main thread.

Comment: I think @ndnenkov is correct that main thread executes the trap. Perhaps that is by design no matter where you define the trap.